# How to deal with "-"suffix when using (UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I use the airdrop function of iPhone, for example, sending one TXT from one device to another. OC will call this function.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  NSString *fileName = url.lastPathComponent;

  NSString *path = url.absoluteString; 

}
```

In this function, I find that when a file with the same name is sent many times, the file path is automatically spliced with suffixes like - 1, - 2, - 3.

> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E4BA66D2-986D-4E67-9D83-672973D7EC40/Documents/Inbox/setting.txt
>
> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E4BA66D2-986D-4E67-9D83-672973D7EC40/Documents/Inbox/setting-1.txt

Just like above, when I use the name of this file, I will add a suffix somehow.

I want to get the real name of the file itself. Please don't tell me, just take the back of the two characters. If the file itself has a suffix like "-".

Comment: I'd go like this: Separate in an array "name", "-", "number", "extension". Check that's it's really a number. Check if you have already a file with "name.extension".

Comment: I have two files now, one is called setting.txt, the other is setting-1.txt. Use the airdrop function to pass these two files to iPhone multiple times.I will get settting-1.txt, settting-2.txt... Stting-1-1.txt, setting-1-2.txt...

Comment: I did a test on WeChat app. I used two identical texts, but I had different names, like setting.txt, setting-1.txt, constantly using airdrop, and using WeChat app to open them, and WeChat kept just storing these two files with setting.txt and setting-1.txt, instead of adding a suffix in the back.

Comment: But most of the app on the market does not have this ability, and whenever you use them to open the file, you get the results of settting-1.txt, settting-2.txt... Stting-1-1.txt, setting-1-2.txt... I now develop a file management app, I do not want to return the result is already suffix. I read Apple's documentation, and there was no explanation. I was curious about how WeChat app handled it.